# How can I make smiley faces next to my Display Name?

Tags: support, display-names

I see many members that have smiley faces at the end of their display name. How can we make those?

Like [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka)

Comment: Question updated with example

Comment: Copy such character (`웃`) and paste in your username.

Comment: I see, is there any list of them to choose from?

Comment: __I don't know why people are voting to close, and now delete this, but it is very on-topic for Meta, and a reasonable support question.__

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not a smiley face; it's [a Korean character](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%9B%83).

Stack Exchange allows for Unicode characters in user's display names. You can add various things like [snowman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%9B%84#Unicode) and arrows if you feel so inclined. Wikipedia has a [List of Unicode Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_characters), and you can try to [draw something](http://shapecatcher.com/) and see if there's a unicode character for it.

Comment: Oh thats very kooooool 웃. +1

Comment: ooops, i tried to add  ☃ to my display name and SO said it is not allowed